# List ComputerName with the powershell result

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a script which gives me the patches & service packs applied on SQL Server by querying the registry. However It does not give me the ComputerName as one of the fields. How can I append the ComputerName to each row of the output?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Select-Object -Property KBNumber, ReleaseType, ParentKeyName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -like "Hotfix*SQL*") -or ($_.DisplayName -like "Service Pack*SQL*")}| Format-table -AutoSize
```

Comment: As a side note, `select @@version` is preferred, as it asks SQL Server itself which version it is running.If you have multiple instances on same server, Registry's uninstaller data might cause a surprise.

Comment: add a `Select-Object` step that builds the desired custom property & adds it ot your property set.

Comment: Or add a calculated property to the Select-Object you already have: `@{Name = 'Computer'; Expression = { $env:COMPUTERNAME }}`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you @Theo and Lee_Daily